# Transforming Line Points According to resized UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have UIImage with size 7017x4962 and have line points A(532,1118) and B(4114,1118).I have reduced the UIImage size to 2339x1654.How can I transform the line points according to new UIImage size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply x and y proportionate to the new image width and height for each coordinate pair:

x * (2339.0f / 7017.0f)

y * (1654.0f / 4962.0f)

This will give you A(177, 372) and B(1371, 372).